# Updating a vuejs alert component from a fetch return value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm having difficulty in updating the text inside a vuetify [`v-alert`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts).

I have a function that logs into a system and returns a sessionid
The issue I have is that within the below code `sessionID.then()` the vue component properties are not defined or cannot be updated.

```
Vue.component('query-status', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <v-alert :type="type">
        {{ alertText }}
      </v-alert>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      alertText: '',
      type: 'success'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkQueryStatus: function() {
      var sessionID = login();
      sessionID.then(function(result) {
        this.alertText = result;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here, why doesn't the `sessionID.then` block have access to the `alertText` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't bind the `this` pointer, the inner function will not have access to it.

You can work around this by either using a local variable:

```
checkQueryStatus : function() {              
  var sessionID = login();
  var that = this;
  sessionID.then(function(result) {
    that.alertText = result;
  });
}
```

Or using an es6 [arrow function:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
checkQueryStatus : function() {              
  var sessionID = login();  
  sessionID.then(result => {
    this.alertText = result;
  });
}
```

or bind the `this` pointer with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
checkQueryStatus : function() {              
  var sessionID = login();  
  sessionID.then(function(result) {
    this.alertText = result;
  }.bind(this));
}
```

As an alternative you could also use [async / await](https://javascript.info/async-await) for this:

```
methods: {
  async checkQueryStatus() {              
    this.alertText = await login();
  }
}
```