# Get Data From PHP And Display In Vue From Fetch

Tags: php, vue.js

I am attempting to learn Vue.js.  I'm working through building a very minimal component. The component is literally just an option list using select.  Nowhere in the documentation, or any tutorials I can find online, does it show how to load data from database into a Vue component.  I have found some examples using Axios, but I have no interest at all in using Axios.  I am simply trying to learn how Vue works, so that I can see if I can use it to improve my workflow.  This is literally a basic test case.  Also, the PHP portion that this code is referencing works fine.  I have tested it directly, and it loads the data exactly as expected.

Here is the javascript portion.

```
const cityChoice = {
    data() {
        return {
            citys: [
                { Abbrev: 'Lima' },
                { Abbrev: 'FtWayne' },
            ],
            err: false
        }
    },

    methods: {

    },
    mounted() {
        fetch('Controller/get_cities.php', {
            method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            headers: {
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
            body: '' // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (data) {
            testData = data
            return testData;
        });

    },

    methods: {
        getCities() {
            fetch('Controller/get_cities.php', {
                method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                headers: {
                    // 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
                referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
                body: '' // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.text();
            }).then(function (data) {
                this.citys = data;
                alert(this.citys)
            });
            this.citys = [
                { Abbrev: 'Dayton' },
                { Abbrev: 'Cincy' },
            ]

        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(cityChoice).mount('#cityChoice')
```

And here is the HTML portion.

```
<?php
$lifetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, '/');
session_start();
include 'Controller/login_check.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <title>BAI Inventory Entry</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cityChoice">
        <select id="city">
            <option v-for="city in citys">
                {{ city.Abbrev }}
            </option>
            </select>
            <button v-on:click="getCities">Get Cities</button>
    </div>
    
</body>
<script src="js/global.js?ver3"></script>
</html>
```

I am positive that I'm just not understanding how this software language works.  But, I need to understand how it calls real data, or else I'm never going to be able to wrap my mind around the other basics of it, because I am constantly finding myself asking "why is this better than just coding it in javascript".  I'm trying to see how to make this simple example work, so that I can get past that question in my head and move forward with learning the language.

I have tried this with using "mounted" and using "created" to load the getCities method, while having the data portion of cities set to ''.  Still no dice.  When hard coding the cities with an array and/or JSON data, it loads exactly as expected.

UPDATE:  I have adjusted the code as what is now shown in the javascript section.  Using chrome tools, I can see that my cities variable is filled with an array of JSON objects, but I'm still not getting any data into the Select list.  I'm completely at a loss as to why this isn't working, as well as why this seems to be so ridiculously difficult to do.  And...this is literally just code to load a few cities into a drop down list.

Update 2:  Apparently Vue will not let the item be updated from inside of a Fetch.  I have updated the code to show my testing. My API returns the data fine, and I have verified it multiple times.  I have tried hard coding the this.citys inside of the final fetch .then portion, and it doesn't work. But, when I hard code it outside of the fetch (as shown in the code above), it works fine.  I'm to the point where I have to assume this is a limitation of Vue, which seems pretty crazy to me.  I found one other question on Stackoverflow that had this same problem, but the answer literally just tells him to do exactly what I've been trying to do above.  And, I'm unable to comment to ask if he found a solution, because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: i think you just need to add a return before `fetch`

Comment: your missing an ending `</select>` tag

Comment: https://medium.com/@disjfa/using-vue-js-in-existing-websites-the-easy-way-d46cd1f0c945

Comment: my previous answer was incorrect i didn't realize you are trying to add it to a page.  but if your starting from scratch and want to use php as your api `nuxt` is a nice solution

Comment: I'm not interested in using nuxt.  I am just trying to improve my skills, so that I can then improve my resume.  I maintain several complex files built with vanilla JS, but every time I attempt to pick up one of these frameworks, I get frustrated because none of the documentation or tutorials give any info on how to work with a real database and PHP backend.  I am seriously questioning why things like Vue and React are pushed so heavily.  The code above would take me 15 to 20 lines of javascript code to be completely finished with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found information at this question that led me to the answer to mine.

[Updating a vuejs alert component from a fetch return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576548/updating-a-vuejs-alert-component-from-a-fetch-return-value)

I will include my updated code in case someone happens past this question instead of the one linked here.

I had to update the response.text() to response.json(), but the biggest issue was the problem of the this not being recognized inside of the fetch function.  I knew that, but in the middle of learning vue, I thought this would behave differently.

```
const cityChoice = {
    data() {
        return {
            citys: [
                { Abbrev: 'Lima' },
                { Abbrev: 'FtWayne' },
            ],
            err: false
        }
    },

    methods: {

    },
    mounted() {
        var self = this;
        fetch('Controller/get_cities.php', {
            method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            headers: {
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
            body: '' // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
            self.citys = data;
        });

    },

    methods: {
        getCities() {
            var self = this;
            fetch('Controller/get_cities.php', {
                method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                headers: {
                    // 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
                referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
                body: '' // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function (data) {
                self.citys = data
            });


        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(cityChoice).mount('#cityChoice')
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who's trying to pick up the new language.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Html
<div id="cityChoice">
    /* <select > to load options on mounted use mounted hook*/
    /* <select v-on:click="getCities">  to load options on click(whatever event)*/
      <option v-for="city in cities">
          {{ city.City }}
      </option>
    </select>
</div>

var app3 = new Vue({
  el: '#cityChoice',
  data(){
    return {
      cities:[],
      err:false
    }
  },
  methods:{
      async getCities() {
        //fetch -> assumption: the php call works -> u can use postman to test this
        let data = await fetch('Controller/get_cities.php', {
          method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      })



      //Data will likely have a data.data field
      if( data in data && !data.error){
        //Set data
        this.cities = data.data //this assumes that data.data is correctly formatted from ur php call
      }else{
        this.err = true
      }
      }
  },
  //Add if you want data loaded on paint
  created(){
 // or mounted(){
    this.getCities()
  }
})
```

See hello world example
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-hello-world

Comment: No.  Nothing from what is in the code example above gives me the information to update my existing code so that it is functional.  The hello world example you linked to does not use an array, therefore doesn't match the use case I'm working on.

Comment: i suspect that the `fetch` library is not configured properly. Looking at your API route it includes only a local reference to `Controller/get_cities.php`. this should be a URL address  (a host address/domain is usually an option for setting up fetch but not required). 
1) Firstly, i would use `postman` determine your API call works and at what address. if it doesnt work why??? `postman` has a lot of options and can handle request with cookies etc. (https://app.getpostman.com/app/download)
2) Review fetch api docs and set it up in 
3) console.log the results from the fetch

Comment: also i would like to note, your question asks about components but your code isnt setup as a component `vue.component('name',{ /*options*/})`
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: I have spent the past three hours working on this.  My fetch library works fine.  The api returns data fine.  When I add an "alert(this.cities)" to the code, it gives me an alert with the JSON data itemized out exactly as it's expected.  For whatever reason, Vue.js is not allowing the this.cities to be updated from inside the fetch call.  I have even tried hard coding this.cities inside of the fetch code to the exact same array I start with, and it doesn't work.  If I do that same hard coding outside of the fetch, it does.